# Expand Ubuntu partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I have 250Gb HDD that is splitted between Ubuntu (20 Gb) and Windows 8.1 (230Gb).

Now I need to have more size for Ubuntu. I suppose scenario in my case should look like:

1. Make Windows partition smaller.
2. Resize Linux partition to make it bigger.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to make these steps, but I think both of them should be possible to make from Ubuntu side.

Would you help me to solve this task?

UPD

I started gparted from Ubuntu booted from live CD.

[image]

I took part of windows partition and now I would like to copy whole sda3 to unallocated place. In this case I expect to have additional space after deleting original sda3 at the bottom of Linux partition. I think that will allow me to expand newly created Linux partition.
From gparted menu I can only copy sda5 - for others copy menu is not active. Probably that is because sda3 and sda5 are with key image that I think means 'locked'. How to solve problem and copy locked partitions.

Comment: You have to boot from the Live DVD/USB version of Ubuntu and do it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "gparted" which is very easy to use and convenient for such tasks and needs, 
  But you need to know that generally partitions' sizes is increased or reduced from their ends by trimming or appending some of the FREE space after it. So take a look at your partitions layout in gparted and you will know if you can expand ubuntu partition, and this is done only by  booting on live edition (you will find gparted shipped with standard ubuntu live cd )

Comment: Can you explain how to do this, otherwise go with the dups =)

Comment: I have updated my question with some steps performed and got stuck in copying locked partitions

Comment: as i can see the only locked is swap wich you can safely delete or shrink when you are on a live ubuntu : right click  --> swap off